# MVC Project memory leaking, how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, c#-4.0, memory-leaks

I've tried everything about that but i couldnt find a solution. On local, there's no problem. But when i publish to  provider hosting. Memory leaking issue is coming out and IIS Recylcling every 75 seconds. I Used memory profiler but, no issue on local like i said. Here's my basecontroller code. Can it cause a memory leak?. And i use  tags in layout. Maybe it causes a memory leak. If you want layout code i can add. For now, my basecontroller code be like;

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }


    internal void ShowErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;
    }
    public List<Categories> GetCategories()
    {
        var catserv = new CategoryService();
        return catserv.GetAll().Where(x => x.Status == DataStatus.Active).ToList();
    }
    public List<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        var prodserv = new ProductService();
        return prodserv.GetAll().ToList();
    }
    public bool CheckAdmin()
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        var member = new MemberService();
        var result = member.GetUserName(username);

        if (result.Data.IsAdmin != 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public string SamePath()
    {
        return Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.ToString();
    }

}
```

GetCategories method is being used for layout. I couldnt add viewmodel entity and i added this method below.
Check my admincontroller and layout.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Member memb)
    {
        var memberservice = new MemberService();
        var getMemberResult = memberservice.Auth(memb.UserName, memb.Password);
        if (getMemberResult.HasError)
        {
            ViewBag.mesaj = getMemberResult.ResultMessage;
            return View();
        }
        if (getMemberResult.Data.Status == DataStatus.Banned)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("BannedUser");
        }
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(getMemberResult.Data.UserName, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Anasayfa", "Magaza");

    }
```

And my layout.. and actually it has var baseController = ViewContext.Controller as web2.Controllers.BaseController; on the top

```
<body>
<div class="banner_bg_main">
    <!-- header top section start -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header_section_top">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="custom_menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Kusursuz Tasarım</li>
                            <li>Profesyonel Çalışmalar</li>
                            <li>Uygun Fiyat Politikası</li>
                            <li>Promosyon Ürünleri</li>
                            <li>Matbaa Ürünleri</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- header top section start -->
    <!-- logo section start -->
    <div class="logo_section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="logo"><a href=@Url.Action("Anasayfa","Magaza")><img style="height:160px;" src="~/Content/img/logo.png"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- logo section end -->
    <!-- header section start -->
    <div class="banner_section layout_padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="my_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h1 class="banner_taital">%100<br>Fiyat Garantisi</h1>
                                <div class="buynow_bt"><a href="https://wa.me/905321517566" target="_blank">Sipariş Ver</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h1 class="banner_taital">Hemen Ürün<br>Siparişinizi Verin</h1>
                                <div class="buynow_bt"><a href="https://wa.me/905321517566" target="_blank">Sipariş Ver</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h1 class="banner_taital">Tamamen isteğe<br>UYGUN TASARIM</h1>
                                <div class="buynow_bt"><a href="https://wa.me/905321517566" target="_blank">Sipariş Ver</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#my_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#my_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_section pb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="containt_main justify-content-center">
                <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                    <a href=@Url.Action("Anasayfa","Magaza")>Anasayfa</a>
                    <a href=@Url.Action("Urunler","Magaza")>Ürünler</a>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <a href=@Url.Action("Menu","Admin")>Admin Menü</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="containt_main">
                <span class="toggle_icon" onclick="openNav()"><img src="~/Content/images/toggle-icon.png"></span>
                <div class="main">
                    <!-- Another variation with a button -->
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Urunler", "Magaza", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <div class="input-group">
                            @Html.TextBox("Ara", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Ürün Arayın", @type = "text" })
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" style="background-color: #f26522; border-color:#f26522">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

                <div class="header_box">
                    <div class="login_menu">
                        <!--<ul>
                           <li><a href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              <span class="padding_10">Cart</span></a>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              <span class="padding_10">Cart</span></a>
                           </li>
                        </ul> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle mb-3" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Kategoriler
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    @foreach (var item in baseController.GetCategories())
                    {
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Urunler","Magaza", new {@kategori = item.Id })">@item.CategoryName</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- header section end -->
    <!-- banner section start -->
    <!-- banner section end -->
</div>
@RenderBody()
<div class="footer_section layout_padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer_logo"><a href="#"><img style="height:100px;" src="~/Content/img/logo.png"></a></div>
        <div class="footer_menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <li>Uygun Fiyat Politikası</li>
                <li>%100 Memnuniyet</li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <li><a href=@Url.Action("Anasayfa","Magaza")><h3 style="color:white">Anasayfa</h3></a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <li><h3 style="color:white">Adres</h3>Rami Cuma Mah.<br /> Oruç Sk. No:20B<br />Eyüp/İstanbul</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="location_main"><a href="https://wa.me/905321517566" target="_blank" style="color:lawngreen">Whatsapp Hattı İçin Tıkla</a></div>
        <div class="location_main"><a href="http://instagram.com/ayaz.promosyon"target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" style="height:55px;" src="~/Content/img/instalogo.png" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/plugin.js"></script>
<!-- sidebar -->
<script src="~/Content/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/css/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function openNav() {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 2 == 1)
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        else
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
</script>
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null || TempData["Fail"] != null)
{
    <script>
        swal.fire({
            title: "Olmadı be",
            text: '@ViewBag.ErrorMessage',
            icon: "error",
        });


    </script>
}
@if (ViewBag.successtoindex != null)
{
    <script>
        swal.fire({

            icon: 'info',
            title: 'Hadi Anasayfaya Dönelim',
            text: '@ViewBag.successtoindex',
            button: 'Hadi Anasayfaya Dönelim!'
        }).then(function () {
            window.location = "/";
        });
    </script>
}
@if (ViewBag.success != null || TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <script>
        swal.fire({
            title: "Mükemmel",
            text: '@ViewBag.success',
            icon: "success",
            button: "Aww yiss!",
        });
    </script>
}
@if (ViewBag.successadminmenu != null)
{
<script>
    swal.fire({
        title: "Başarılı",
        text: '@ViewBag.successadminmenu',
        icon: "success",
        button: "Muhteşem!",
    }).then(function () {
        window.location = "menu";
    });;


</script>
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-native-memory-leak-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool) about how to fix memory leaking on IIS. It uses [debugdiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) to capture application data and debugdiag analysis to analysis the log file.

Comment: @BruceZhang thank you. But i tried it, not problem for localhost, it uses about 140 mb. The real issue starts when i publish this site on a hosting.

Comment: Why you filter your category data after fetching all of that? GetAll().Where(x => x.Status  ....... 
and what inside your service (productService,...)

Comment: @MahdiFarhani it includes some code that reaches to repository. GetAll is a list that returns a list. repository.SelectAll(); and return selectall.tolist(); and selectall is a list which returns dbset.tolist();

Comment: I prefer to post your code here, so everyone can check it

Comment: debugdiag not only can capture data on local machine, but also on windows server.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your service layer (eg. CategoryService).